# oxmplayer is on top and blocking every other GUI application

Tags: x11, xorg, display

I want to display notifications popups(`osd_cat`) on my screen while running oxmplayer but it seems that the latter is on top of everything and doesn't allow the notification to appear.

I run the video using the command `oxmplayer -o hdmi video.mp4`

I managed how to display notifications using `osd_cat` on my Debian/Raspbian os's screen without the oxmplayer.

Is it possible to diplay `osd_cat` while running oxmplayer ?
is there any  other alternative to do this (using python, ...) ?